# Uninstall batch file not working Closes out

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, command-prompt

have the below file.

My end goal is to check for a file in a directory if this file exists don't do anything

if the file does not exist uninstall teamviewer on that pc

Here's the below script

```
IF EXIST C:\store\TV-DONOTDELETE.TXT

(echo Found the file won't do anything.)
pause

ELSE
(
REM Kill TeamViewer Process
taskkill /f /im teamviewer*
REM Remove Older Versions
for /d %%F in ("C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\*") do "%%F\uninstall.exe" /S
for /d %%F in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\*") do "%%F\uninstall.exe" /S
REM Remove Newer Versions
"C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\uninstall.exe" /S
"C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\uninstall.exe" /S

echo removed teamviewer you can thank me later
)
pause
```

Comment: The IF command help file literally has an example for using `IF EXIST ELSE`.  Clearly you didn't read the help file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys this is the final result of all the research you all recommended.

```
@echo off
CD C:\store\

if exist "TV-DONOTDELETE.TXT" (
    echo "Found the file won't do anything."
    pause

) ELSE (
    REM Kill TeamViewer Process
    taskkill /f /im teamviewer*
    REM Remove Older Versions
    for /d %%F in ("C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\*") do "%%F\uninstall.exe" /S
    for /d %%F in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\*") do "%%F\uninstall.exe" /S
    REM Remove Newer Versions
    "C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\uninstall.exe" /S
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\uninstall.exe" /S

    echo "Removed teamviewer"

    md c:\store
    CD c:\store\
    type nul >TV-DONOTDELETE.txt

    echo "Created the file, now you can thank me later"

    pause
)
```

Comment: As you were able to properly mark your code in the question, why didn't you on your answer?